# Could override be deprecated?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

There is a Design Principle that says *Favor composition over inheritance* and its advertised benefit is that it *simplifies design*. Let's agree on that as background for this question.

So, could override be deprecated? **Could** we, in theory, get rid of it for good?

Let's be a bit over zealous on the above mentioned Design Principle and take it to the extreme: composition all the way. One reason should be enough for now, *override abuse*.

One question arises: are we, programmers, going to loose something? Is any power lost trying to prevent some possible abuse?

So, what applications are there for override and can they be achieved otherwise? Should they?

Comment: If for nothing else, backwards compatibility: if we _had it_, therefore people will _need it_.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: let's say compatibility is not an issue yet

Comment: So, everything should be `sealed`? And, a `Bear` should have a sub-element `Animal` as composite, as opposed to a `Bear` _also_ being an `Animal`? That's a pretty large argument _for_ inheritance, and subsequently, overriding - the `Animal.Eat` method shouldn't consume the same amount of food.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/11/favor-composition-over-inheritance-and-other-pithy-catch-phrases.aspx

Comment: short answer:yes. because object-oriented programming does not provide a good mapping to real world

Comment: using encapsulation right, you say Door.close() as if the door closes itself, instead of saying Person.close(door); and i'm saying this because, since the Door object has the state saying if door is closed or not, using encapsulation and hiding the door's state, the close() method should be in the Door object. what i am saying is that the kind of examples we are taught in school (like the one you provided) are bad (my initial question can we rewritten to: could the relationship *is-a* be dropped from oop?)

Answer (score 4):

Not only is this a completely radical and impractical proposal, it's not a particularly compelling one. Just because a feature gets abused doesn't mean that it should be removed entirely. People have been abusing all sorts of things for a very long time, but that hardly implies that they don't serve a useful purpose when used correctly.

Design patterns are one thing; designing an intentionally limited language to conform with your ideal notion of a good design pattern is quite another. To my mind, it's an exercise in futility. Programmers will still find something to abuse.

And I take issue with the central assumption that any use of `override` is inappropriate or abusive. There are lots of cases where you want to take advantage of inheritance implying an **is-a** relationship. Sure, this model doesn't fit the real world 100% of the time, but there are plenty of times that it does.

The `Animal` and `Shape` class examples that you read about in textbooks might be a bit contrived, but I frequently use inheritance in real-world applications.

That's not to imply that I disagree with the sentiment that one should generally or when in doubt, favor composition over inheritance. But that's *not* saying that inheritance is bad and should never be used.

Comment: i agree with 'Just because a feature gets abused doesn't mean that it should be removed entirely'. but i still wanted to explore the idea that this could work. just because, think of it, this is feature of OOP. somebody put it there. what is he/she didn't?

Comment: all answers seem to point to 'ease and readability', so far, as arguments for override...

Comment: @Belun: That's what it *all* gets down to. High-level design patterns do not allow your code to do anything that it wouldn't be able to do in any other Turing-complete language. They're all tools for the programmer. But that's nothing to sneeze at!

Answer (score 3):

If you remove inheritance altogether you remove a significant feature of OOP design.
Using inheritance allows you to use a "**is a**" design, which has a strong meaning in OOP design, and of course saves code redundancy.

If you'd use only encapsulation you'd have to either expose the members (which isn't always what you want (raises design complexity because of the amount of stuff the programmer needs to know about).
Or, make wrapper methods that will call the member's methods (which is redundant).

Besides that, lets assume you know the difference between [overriding and hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding), you can see that most OOP languages will choose to use strictly overriding when given the choice.
This is because overriding is usually more intuitive than hiding.

So, if you remove overriding, and still allow inheritance, you are left with hiding. That usually leads to many runtime errors and un-expected results with type conflicts.

Farther more you won't be able to have things like an array or list of base class pointers that point a lot of different derived classes. Because if you don't have overrides it won't be able to call the specified derived class method, it will only call the same base class method for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a response on behalf of **astander** extracting from [his link](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/11/favor-composition-over-inheritance-and-other-pithy-catch-phrases.aspx) (hope you don't mind)

> For example, one advantage with inheritance is that it is easier to
>   use than composition. However, that ease of use comes at the cost that
>   it is harder to reuse because the subclass is tied to the parent
>   class.
>
> One advantage of composition is that it is more flexible because
>   behavior can be swapped at runtime. One disadvantage of composition is
>   that the behavior of the system may be harder to understand just by
>   looking at the source. These are all factors one should think about
>   when applying composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using polymorphism.  I always seem to have a bunch of objects with some common concept behind them and a lot of code that is interested in that concept--that is, they care about Animals, not Lions and Tigers and Bears or even Carnivores.  Interfaces often work better for this than superclasses, so I suppose I could get by without subclassing.  (Are interfaces okay when subclassing is not?)  However, I have often found that a lot of classes using an interface have identical code for the interface methods.  Changing the interface to a superclass can let me get rid of a lot of duplicate code.  The other situation I find myself in is where a large, complex class does what I need except for one teeny, tiny little thing.  With subclassing, I can create a new class that does exactly what I need in just a few lines.

There may be a language component to this debate.  When I'm writing in Java I subclass at a furious rate.  When I'm writing in C# I think long and hard before overriding anything or even using interfaces.  I'm not sure why and it may have more to do with the type of work I do in those languages than the languages themselves.  But working in C#, I am quite sympathetic to this idea, while when working in Java...well, I'd have to toss almost all my Java code if I couldn't override.

Comment: for the case where, "a large, complex class does what I need except for one teeny, tiny little thing" use dependency injection. the design principle applied is 'separate what is common from what is going to differ, extract what is going to differ and inject that'; this way you can inject another tinny thing if needed, not subclass for it.

Comment: For dependency injection, you have to modify that original class, which might be hard to do if it came from a Microsoft or Sun library, or if it's now used by a lot of people who don't want you to mess with it.  Over time, you may want to make other changes, multiplying the problem.  Again, I think there's a language component.  In Java I can always override, it's easy, it's simple, the code looks good, and nothing outside the code I'm writing is affected.  In C# not so much; I'm going to be a lot quicker to use dependency injection.